# Does UNIQUE automatically add an index?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, indexing, unique

Or do I have to create index manually?

```
CREATE TABLE pages(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  stitle TEXT UNIQUE,
  parent INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(parent) REFERENCES pages(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So I should have 2 indexes, right? id and stitle

Comment: I would hope so, otherwise it might take longer to verify uniquness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a `UNIQUE` constraint automatically creates an index on the columns involved in the UNIQUE constraint.

[Ref](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).

> both UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by creating
>   an index in the database.
>
> .... As a result, there often no advantage (but significant overhead)
>   in creating an index on a set of columns that are already collectively
>   subject to a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint.

In your example, there would be 2 indexes created.